# Should I be testing an entire business flow in a MQ/Service architecture?

Tags: testing, rabbitmq, integration-testing, message-queue

I'm trying to decouple the code that sends emails out into a separate service with rabbitMQ has a means of communication between the services.

Currently, I have integration tests that tests our HTTP endpoints that's something like this:

```
1. Create fake data in a dockerized mysql container. So that the DB is in the correct state
2. Perform testable action such as: User needs to approve a contract
3. Expect that the `contract.status` is now `approved`
4. Query a local SMTP server (Mailhog) to see if the email is there
5. Expect that email subject/body contains what I'm expecting
```

Now that I plan on putting a message queue in the mix. Should I still be writing integration tests like this? How should I be writing my tests so that I can still test that an email is sent when performing this action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the whole solution is under your responsibility, you should definitely write integration tests for the whole solution.

As [Martin Fowler](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/IntegrationTest.html) states:

> Integration tests determine if independently developed units of software work correctly when they are connected to each other.

Writing the tests depends on your concrete implementation. I think you'll have to create test data and perform an action (steps 1 to 3) and then check the results, regardless of the existence of a MQ.